# Connecting two gatsby nodes

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

So, I'm using the [gatsby-mdx](http://gatsby-mdx.netlify.com/) plugin to create a site from MDX files. I want to create an association between the SitePage object and the Mdx object so that I can do one graphQL query of the SitePage edges in order to construct a site navigation.

Much of my code is in TypeScript, so ignore any type annotations if you're wondering WTF those are.

## Things I've tried

### Using Fields

My first thought was to use the [`onCreateNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode) API, grab the MDX node, and add it to the SitePage using the `createNodeField` action. That all works great, B-U-T the gatsby-mdx plugin [adds a bunch of other info to their node](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx/blob/master/packages/gatsby-mdx/gatsby/extend-node-type.js) later using the [`setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType) API (which occurs *after* the `onCreateNode` API).  I want those fields (such as frontmatter and tableOfContents) to be available in later graphql queries, but they aren't using this method.

### Implementing my own `setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType`

I figured I could just extend the SitePage object the same way gatsby-mdx was extending the Mdx node.

The key problem I ran into here was that I couldn't figure out how to create the Mdx GraphQL node type.

```
export const setFieldsOnGraphQLNodeType = ({type, actions, getNodes}: any, pluginOptions: any) => {
    if (type.name === "SitePage") {
        const {createParentChildLink} = actions
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            return resolve({
                "childMdx": {
                    type: new GraphQLObjectType({
                        name: 'Mdx'
                    }),
                    async resolve(sitePageNode: any) {
                        const allNodes = getNodes()
                        if (sitePageNode.component &&
                            (sitePageNode.component.endsWith(".mdx") || sitePageNode.component === DefaultLayout)
                        ) {
                            const associatedMdx = allNodes.find((mdxNode: any) =>
                                mdxNode.internal.type === 'Mdx' && mdxNode.fileAbsolutePath === sitePageNode.component
                            )
                            if (associatedMdx) {
                                console.log("Found associated MDX node", associatedMdx.id)
                                console.log("Adding it to the sitepage node", sitePageNode.id)
                                return associatedMdx
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
    return {}
}
```

I also tried simply passing the type as a String ('Mdx'), but that failed too.

### Using Parent-Child Links

That plugin creates a parent-child link between the File node and the parsed MDX node in the `onCreateNode` API, using the [createParentChildLink](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createParentChildLink) action ([source](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx/blob/master/packages/gatsby-mdx/gatsby/on-create-node.js#L55)).

I tried implementing that...

```
export const onCreateNode = ({node, actions, getNodes}: OnCreateNodeArgument) => {
    const {createParentChildLink} = actions
    const allNodes = getNodes()
    if (node.internal && node.internal.type === 'SitePage' && node.component &&
        (node.component.endsWith(".mdx") || node.component === DefaultLayout)
    ) {
        const associatedMdx = allNodes.find((mdxNode: any) =>
            mdxNode && mdxNode.internal && mdxNode.internal.type === 'Mdx' &&
                (mdxNode.fileAbsolutePath === node.component || mdxNode.fileAbsolutePath === node.context.fileAbsolutePath)
        )
        if (associatedMdx) {
            console.log("Found associated MDX node", associatedMdx.id)
            console.log("Adding it to the sitepage node as a child", node.id)
            createParentChildLink({parent: node, child: associatedMdx})
        }
    }
}
```

At first, that appears to succeed, but the [`tableOfContents` property](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx/blob/master/packages/gatsby-mdx/gatsby/extend-node-type.js#L192) that gatsby-mdx adds to the Mdx node still isn't available in a graphQL query like:

```
{
    allSitePage(filter: {fields: {childMdx: {id: {ne: null}}}}) {
        edges {
            node {
                path
                fields{
                    childMdx {
                        tableOfContents
                        fileAbsolutePath
                        frontmatter {
                            title
                        }
                    }
                }
                context {
                    roughFilePath
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Other (possibly irrelevant) info

I'm [creating some pages programmatically](https://gatsby-mdx.netlify.com/guides/programmatically-creating-pages) in gatsby-node.js.

I've seen a suggestion for similar use cases to use [node type mappings](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/#mapping-node-types), but I since my mapping between the SitePage & the MDX object requires a bit of finesse (specifically, reading some things from siteMetadata and doing a string comparison), I don't think that will work for my use case.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't all mdx files already be a part of sitePage nodes? if your purpose is to construct a site navigation, won't you be able to find all the generated pages there?

Comment: So, the SitePage nodes don't directly link to their associated Mdx node in graphql queries without some intervention. There's some specific information on the Mdx nodes that I want for the navigation: frontmatter and tableOfContents.

Those aren't on the SitePage node itself. While I can do one big query of both `allSitePage` and `allMdx`, then finagle them together using JavaScript, that... well, kind of sucks! By all appearances, I should be able manipulate the SitePage nodes to include the information I want, but the timing of the various phases complicates matters.

Comment: The `createParentChildLink` action seems like the most appropriate solution. I may just need to make a deep debugger dive on that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'internal' of undefined` message.

Comment: Updated question, as that cryptic error went away after I cleared the .cache folder and restarted.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional context, I've never dealt with this but it's probably good to know how. I've just shared my findings as an answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I finally found a better solution (than my previous attempt, which involves pumping mdx node into page’s `context`).

Gatsby has a [undocumented method](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1583#issuecomment-317827660) to link nodes to one another:

> Yes, you can can use createNodeField with the not-yet-documented ___NODE syntax to create links between nodes.

So, the steps are like this:

- In `createPage`, store the `id` of the Mdx node to SitePage node.
- In `onCreateNode`, if node is `SitePage`, use `createNodeField` with the `Mdx___NODE` as field name and Mdx node's id as value.

My `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const path = require("path")
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === "SitePage" && node.context && node.context.id) {

    createNodeField({
      name: "Mdx___NODE",
      value: node.context.id,
      node,
    })
  }

  if (node.internal.type === "Mdx") {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      // 1) this is the name of the field you are adding,
      name: "slug",
      // 2) this node refers to each individual MDX
      node,
      value: `/blog${value}`
    })
  }
}


exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const { data, errors } = await graphql(`
    {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (errors) throw errors
  data.allMdx.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/components/posts-page-layout.js`),
      context: { id: node.id }
    });
  });
};
```

Result:

[image: graphiql]

Hope it helps!

Comment: It definitely does! Thanks.