# Gatsby combine javascript frontmatter with allSitePage query

Tags: gatsby

What i'm trying to do is query for all pages along with some frontmatter (not from markdown, but using transformer-javascript-frontmatter method). The idea is to create a menu type listing of the pages, with the path and a friendly title that comes from frontmatter.

this query works fine to get the front matter, but i dont have access to page level data like the path

```
{
  allJavascriptFrontmatter {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and getting path is easy

```
{
  allSitePage {
    edges {
      node {
        path
      }
    }
  }
}
```

seems like there needs to be some type of resolver to take an id from one node and query against page info / frontmatter info? it seems odd to have to manually define path again in frontmatter just to be able to get it as part of the one query.

Comment: If I follow correctly, you want to attach the frontmatter node to its sitePage node. Check out [this answer here, doing something very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54209955/10340970)